# unable to set background color for multiple tags with a new tag running between them in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add a background color for a couple of tags where in i created a new tag that runs in between them but i dont see the background color from the start of the tag to the end it just doent run on the next element

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>hea<selection divid="divid" style="background-color: yellow">fig</h1>
    <p>ghfshgsjgsjfjg</selection> ghfshgsjgsjfjg ghfshgsjgsdasdaddajfjg ghfshgsjgsjfjg</p>
</body>

</html>
```

want to actually get the background color yellow until the "selection" tag ends which includes half of "h1" and a "p" tag, how do I achieve this ?

Comment: That's not valid HTML.

Comment: First of all your html is pretty messed up and invalid. There is no html tag called `selection` and it's not even closed.

Comment: @VilleKoo It is closed. But not at the proper place.

Comment: @Zlytherin yeah, didn't even see that :D

Comment: i understand that there is not tag named `selection` i just want to create my own as i have a requirement as such and i think its closed after the `style` and before the innerHTML `fig` if iam not wrong @VilleKoo

Comment: [codepen link] (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOjbXN#anon-login) . refer this please

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it half h1 and half p then something like this would be the proper way:

```
<h1>hea<selection divid="divid" style="background-color: yellow">fig</selection></h1>
<p>ghfshgsjgsjfjg ghfshgsjgsjfjg<selection divid="divid" style="background-color: yellow"> ghfshgsjgsdasdaddajfjg ghfshgsjgsjfjg</selection></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any way I could achieve the same with a single tag as I am working on creating this tag dynamically when the user selects the text.

Comment: Actually I dont think so, but I am not sure about it. With my knowledge I would say no.

Comment: Cool but is there anyway i could get the selected text along with the tag enclosed for the text when i select the text? using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct your HTML.

```
<html>
<body><h1>hea<span class="highlight">fig</span></h1>
<p><span class="highlight">ghfshgsjgsjfjg</span> ghfshgsjgsjfjg 
 ghfshgsjgsdasdaddajfjg ghfshgsjgsjfjg</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Include the below CSS also.

```
.highlight {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any way I could achieve the same using a single span which runs across from the start to the end of the text? as I am working on selecting text and highlighting the background.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these tiny css to your css. It'll colorize the selection text

```
::-moz-selection { background: yellow; }
::selection { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks buddy can you please add sample code for a working example of this? please.

Comment: This works but i am working on a project where i have to select a text from a HTML page and then highlight the text which is selected and surrounded by a selection tag to uniquely identify the text can you give me some ideas on how do i achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, you can with some piece of javascript but you'll face with some restriction. For examle, if you have a lot of nested span, header tags, div etc. and want to select text in the middle of them to the other one's middle you can not surrond the selected text with the select tag that you want to create. You might want to check for select and highlightining text : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text/5379408#5379408

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property :before and :first-line if you want to it without single span and something like below.Please check code snippet other wise its not possible without span.

If you want it dynamically then create your html dynamically with span element which is better.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.heading {
color: black;
}
.heading:before {
 color: red;
 content: "First ";
 
}
p::first-line {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
</style>
<h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
<p class="text">You can use the ::first-line pseudo-element to add a<br/>
special effect to the first line of a text. Some more text. And even more, and more, and more, and more, and more, and more, and more, and more, and more, and more, and more, and more.</p>
 
</body>

</html>
```